# Log in with paypal by @paypal/react-paypal-js

Tags: reactjs, paypal

Our users need to verify their PayPal accounts in order to receive payments.

The more information about log in with paypal is described here : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/

To implement this feature, we are using @paypal/react-paypal-js, but their documentation does not provide any details.

We have previously used this library to implement payment, and everything has gone smoothly.

While reading the @paypal/react-paypal-js documentation, I could not find any information that was helpful for implementing the log in with paypal feature.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@paypal/react-paypal-js is for PayPal Checkout integrations. It is not for Log in with PayPal.

To integrate Log in with PayPal, see the non-react documentation at the link in your question. You can also review the Seller Onboarding integration information: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/seller-onboarding/

None of this uses @paypal/react-paypal-js